# What is best naming conventions for long class name?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, flask, conventions, pep8

Now, I'm writing Python-flask codes to MVC Pattern.
But, I consider myself, I think declarator of controller class is too long

For example, I have

```
class GoogleQuestionController:
    def __init__(self):

        (.....)
```

and

```
class YahooQuestionController:
    def __init__(self):

        (.....)
```

two of very similar class name, so I can't define declarator like

```
question_controller = GoogleQuestionController()
```

above.

What is best suggestion to define class declarator?

```
google_question_controller = GoogleQuestionController()
yahoo_question_controller = YahooQuestionController()
```

This code is too long,

So, I'm using like this now.

```
yq_con = YahooQuestionController()
gq_con = GoogleQuestionController()
```

or

```
gqc = GoogleQuestionController()
yqc = YahooQuestionController()
```

Comment: `x,y=GQC(),YQC()`. Remember, always value code length over readability. Always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Context is important here:

```
google_question_controller = GoogleQuestionController()
yahoo_question_controller = YahooQuestionController()
```

might be ok, but if we were able to refactor so that the noun wasn't ambiguous i.e. if there were only one google object I might use:

```
google = GoogleQuestionController()
yahoo = YahooQuestionController()
```

Similarly, if the verb wasn't ambiguous, e.g. if I was inside a Google object/module, I'd use `question` (or perhaps `controller`):

```
class GoogleSomething(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.question = GoogleQuestionController()  # or perhaps `controller`

class YahooSomething(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.question = YahooQuestionController()
```

*In this way there might be a way in which you could rewrite your code to improve readability.*

Often, in cases like this, grouping together similar behaviors can lead to better abstractions, for example we might be able to define a mixin/base class which makes use of `self.controller` using a shared API between `GoogleQuestionController` and `YahooQuestionController` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is not the answer you're looking for but I would highly recommend you actually choose :

```
google_question_controller = GoogleQuestionController()
yahoo_question_controller = YahooQuestionController()
```

I don't consider this as too long, it is actually readable and neat.

Now, opinions asides, remember that [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) has no restrictions on length, but highly value readability for variables:

> Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by
>   underscores as necessary to improve readability.